# Why local version of Angular app outputs error?

Tags: angularjs

I created a local version of this [example](https://codepen.io/winniehsu/pen/ZBYmvr).

This example works both with Angular 1.3 and 1.5 in a Codepen.
But there's an error in a [console](http://joxi.ru/eAOY3eWuxlDJXm) in a local version.
The code is the same:

```
angular.module("winnieApp", []);
angular.module("winnieApp").controller("winnieCtrl", ['$scope', 
'$filter', function($scope, $filter){

  $scope.friendsArr = [{"id": 1, "name":"Winnie", "age": 76, "food": "hunny"},
                     {"id": 2, "name":"Piglet", "age": 43, "food": "grains"},
                     {"id": 3, "name":"Tigger", "age": 52, "food": "meat"},
                     {"id": 4, "name":"Rabbit", "age": 34, "food": "carrot"},
                     {"id": 5, "name":"Eeyore", "age": 63, "food": "grass"}];

  $scope.search = {
    setFilter: function(method){ $scope.search.currentFilter = 
    $scope.search[method]; },
    allage: function(data){ return true; },
    ageLow: function(data){ return data.age < 50; },
    ageHeight: function(data){ return data.age >= 50; },
  };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. There was 'ng-app="countryApp"' in my HTML tag.